# Pulling records between two dates from a VIEW

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a mysql datetime field that stores dates in the form `'2013-12-25 00:00:00'`
I need to select all records for any month in the table with a query like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM `images` 
        WHERE (photodate BETWEEN '2003-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2003-12-03 00:00:00')
        ORDER BY photodate DESC
        LIMIT 30";
```

The above select query does the job fine.

In order to change the dates, I need to replace the `'2003-11-01 00:00:00'AND'2003-12-03 00:00:00'` with variables, so I set a variable with input data from two drop down lists for `$startyear` and `$startmonth` and convert it to what I think is the correct form using:

```
$startdate = $startyear."-".$startmonth."-01 00:00:00";
```

I do the same to the `$enddate` by adding `1` to the `$startmonth`.

My code then becomes:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM `images`
        WHERE (photodate BETWEEN $startdate AND  $enddate)
        ORDER BY photodate DESC
        LIMIT 30";
```

This does not work at all and gives a MySQL error. Having struggled with it for a month and finding nothing on any forum that uses variables instead of text, I am totally at a loss as to how it could be done. All help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), which is why it's not working. You're producing the literal query

```
... WHERE (photodate BETWEEN 2003-11-01 00:00:00 AND 2013-12-03 00:00:00)
```

The `2003-11-01` and `2013-12-03` will be interpreted as a series of mathematical subtractions, and the `00:00:00` will be a simple flat-out syntax error. You need to, at bare minimum, quote those values:

```
... WHERE (photodate BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate')
                             ^----------^-----^--------^--- note the quotes
```

so that mysql can see the WHOLE date as a date value, and not some arbitrary broken strings.

Comment: The vulnerability to SQL injections isn't why it's not working, but it is still a problem and should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're missing some apostrophes... try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE (photodate BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate') ORDER BY photodate DESC LIMIT 30";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have problems with the logic. In `$enddate` doesn't adding 1 to the start month give you 13?

Try printing out the contents `$sql` when the variables are in and see how it compares to the working `$sql`.

Comment: I changed the code as follows: $enddate=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($startyear."-".$startmonth+1)); which automatically corrects the overflow to 13 problem.

Comment: Or so I thought... Need to redo the logic as stated above.

Comment: Could you convert to epoch time, add your time to it this way and then convert back to the date format you need?

Comment: I made a function to add the correct number of days to the month. That way it never causes a problem at the year end.<?PHP
function last_date($yr,$mth) 
{
$a[1] = 30;
$a[2]=28;
$a[3]=31;
$a[4]=30;
$a[5]=31;
$a[6]=30;
$a[7]=31;
$a[8]=31;
$a[9]=31;
$a[10]=31;
$a[11]=30;
$a[12]=31;
$time=$yr."-".$mth."-".$a[$mth];
return $time;
}
 
echo  last_date(2013,1)
?>

Comment: Revised:`code` <?PHP
function last_date($yr,$mth) 
{
$a[1] = 30;
$a[2]=28;
$a[3]=31;
$a[4]=30;
$a[5]=31;
$a[6]=30;
$a[7]=31;
$a[8]=31;
$a[9]=31;
$a[10]=31;
$a[11]=30;
$a[12]=31;
$day=$a[$mth]." 00:00:00";
if ($mth<10) $mth="0".$mth;
$time=$yr."-".$mth."-".$day;
return $time;
}
 echo last_date(2013,11);
 ?>

Answer (score 0):

Please add apostrophes your query (and sanitize your variables using mysql_real_escape_string, PDO bind values, mysqli_real_escape_string) :

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM 'images' WHERE (photodate BETWEEN '.$startdate.' AND  '.$enddate.') ORDER BY photodate DESC  LIMIT 30';
```

A little reminder, you shall NOT use MySQL (deprecated, old.. and not that fast), if you're using MySQLi or going to use it, please sanitize your variables like this, as Marc B said it could break your script and your app security :

```
<?php

// Starting MySQLi Connection
$db = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "password", "dbname");

// Sanitizing your variables
$startdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $startdate);
$enddate = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $enddate);

// Query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'images' WHERE (photodate BETWEEN ".$startdate." AND  ".$enddate.") ORDER BY photodate DESC  LIMIT 30";

// Doing the query and print the result array
$var = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
print_r($var);

// Closing connection
mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Please refer to [to this](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) for PDO way or [to this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) for MySQLi way, you can also check the MySQL_real_escape_string into PHP doc but MySQL functions are deprecated since PHP 5.5